# Edit views inside layout that's not inflated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Quick question. I want to edit a view inside of a layout, while another layout is inflated. Which then of course says that it can't because it thinks it's a null object. I could inflate the layout, do the changes, and then switch back to the old layout, but that seems very inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There's no point in "editing" `View`s in a layout until it's inflated. Whatever changes you make to `View` objects in your code have no effect on the XML the `View`s are inflated from, and each time you inflate a layout, the `View`s are new, different instances.

Comment: Post your code or face the wrath of closure.  :P